# Concatenate .map() values

Tags: javascript

I have used .map() to created query parameters from an object of values from a form.

```js
let object = {
  "selectedPriority": "9",
  "selectedShipOption": "Private Label",
  "selectedCustomerStatus": "No",
  "selectedColdOptions": [],
  "selectedDistributionOptions": ["Retail"],
  "selectedPackagingOption": "Lid",
  "selectedPrepOption": "Hot Water",
  "productParams": ["Kosher\n"],
  "productAppearance": "Grill Marks",
  "storage": "CAP",
  "preservatives": "Only natural preservatives"
}

Object.keys(object).map((key, index) => {
  console.log(`?${key}=${object[key]}`)
});
```

Now that I've manipulated each object and key, I'd like to concatenate all of them together to create one query string.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `.map` isn't actually mapping anything right now - it's only `console.log`ging and returning `undefined`.

If you want a query string, you should only add a `?` before the *first*, and have a `&` between all the parameters. So, you might `join` by `&` and add `?` to the beginning.

You may also consider using `Object.entries` to get both the key and value at once, rather than having to reference `object[key]`.

You should also probably use `encodeURIComponent` to transform characters not safe for URLs (like plain spaces) into their proper escape sequences (like `%20`):

```js
const object = {
  "selectedPriority": "9",
  "selectedShipOption": "Private Label",
  "selectedCustomerStatus": "No",
  "selectedColdOptions": [],
  "selectedDistributionOptions": ["Retail"],
  "selectedPackagingOption": "Lid",
  "selectedPrepOption": "Hot Water",
  "productParams": ["Kosher\n"],
  "productAppearance": "Grill Marks",
  "storage": "CAP",
  "preservatives": "Only natural preservatives"
}

const result = '?' + Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => {
  return `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`
}).join('&');
console.log(result);
```

Another option that doesn't require creating an intermediate array is to use `reduce`, passing an initial value of `?`:

```js
const object = {
  "selectedPriority": "9",
  "selectedShipOption": "Private Label",
  "selectedCustomerStatus": "No",
  "selectedColdOptions": [],
  "selectedDistributionOptions": ["Retail"],
  "selectedPackagingOption": "Lid",
  "selectedPrepOption": "Hot Water",
  "productParams": ["Kosher\n"],
  "productAppearance": "Grill Marks",
  "storage": "CAP",
  "preservatives": "Only natural preservatives"
};

const result = Object.entries(object).reduce((a, [key, value], i) => (
  a + (i !== 0 ? '&' : '' ) + `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`
), '?');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate them by applying the [`join` function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp).

```js
const object = {
  "selectedPriority": "9",
  "selectedShipOption": "Private Label",
  "selectedCustomerStatus": "No",
  "selectedColdOptions": [],
  "selectedDistributionOptions": ["Retail"],
  "selectedPackagingOption": "Lid",
  "selectedPrepOption": "Hot Water",
  "productParams": ["Kosher\n"],
  "productAppearance": "Grill Marks",
  "storage": "CAP",
  "preservatives": "Only natural preservatives"
};

const result = Object.keys(object)
  .map((key, index) => `?${key}=${object[key]}`)
  .join('\n');

console.log(result);
```

In case you are trying to create a URL query string, don't repeat the `?` and encode the values by applying `encodeURIComponent` to each of them, then join with `&`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance perfectly demonstrated the URL creation use-case.